# Поменять цвет Path в Custom View

Tags: android, kotlin, customview

У меня в `Custom View` много путей, которые я реализовал через `class Path`. Эти пути ялвяются ребрами между вершинами. Все пути и их координаты я храню в классе `Node`. Как можно поменять цвет путей. Я отработал нажатие на вершину в точке, где есть вершина, но не могу понять как поменять цвет этих путей. Как можно поменять цвет путей при нажатии?

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        for(i in 0 until chapterAdapter.nodes.size){
            if(chapterAdapter.nodes[i].rect.contains(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())){
               Toast.makeText(context, "SUCCESS".plus(event.x.toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               return true
            }
        }

    return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял как это можно сделать, достаточно реализовать функцию, которая будет изменять цвет и перерисовать нужные пути от нода заново с другим цветом. Важно вызвать эту фунцию в `OnDraw` и вызвать после нашей функции `invalidate()` для перерисовки.